# C# ASP.NET| ошибка 502 bad gateway при первом входе на сайт

Tags: c#, asp.net

Есть сайт на с# asp.net .net core 3.1 MVC. В продакшене при первом заходе на сайт появляется ошибка 502 bad gateway, если перезагрузить страницу, то данная ошибка пропадает и в течении некоторого времени не появляется, можно спокойно перезагружать страницу - ничего не будет. Если зайти на сайт через некоторое время, то история повторяется - первый заход ошибка, потом все ок. На тестовом опубликованном стенде данной ошибки нет, только на действующем проекте она появляется. Сам я в asp.net не силен, определить почему она появляется не могу, дать конкретики по проекту тоже. Если напишите предполагаемые ошибки, на что стоит обратить внимание, что посмотреть, при каких сценариях у вас появлялось что-то подобное, может особенности данной платформы - буду благодарен.

Comment: Если хостинг в IIS, то возможно из-за того что сайт выгружается из пула т.к. не используется. Если сайт под постоянной нагрузкой, то дело в чём то другом

Comment: Если есть 502-ая, то значит, где то и логи со стектрейсом должны быть, в которых можно будет найти причину...пока же на данный вопрос невозможно объективно ответить. Нужны детали.